# Apollo GraphQL Playground not working in Safari MacOs Big Sur

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo-server, ngrok

Cannot load Apollo Server on safari. It returns an error that reads.

```
Safari does not support network requests from Studio on HTTPS to your local HTTP endpoint, so we cannot introspect your endpoint.

There are a couple solutions:
Visit this page from a browser that supports HTTPS requests to local HTTP endpoints, like Chrome or Firefox.
Set up an SSL certificate for your local endpoint.
```

Decided to try the second solution by spinning up `ngrok`. Which also returns a `[Error] Fetch API cannot load https://7676-576-98-1-248.ngrok.io/ due to access control checks.`

I am passing the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` Headers.

Any guess on what can be done?